# How do I do a JavaScript redirect in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

The following code will generate a link to the page I want to get to.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(image.Title, image.Id.ToString(), "Image") %>
```

The following code will cause the correct url to be rendered on the page.

```
<%= Url.Action("Index", "Image", new { id = image.Id })%>
```

But when I try to use it in javascript it fails. (with some strange error about page inheritance)

```
<div onclick="window.location = '<%= Url.Action("Index", "Image", new { id = image.Id })%>'">
    ...
</div>
```

Should the above code work? What is the correct way to generate the javascript attempted above?

**Update** There error I get is

> Views\Home\Index.aspx.cs(9): error
>   ASPNET: Make sure that the class
>   defined in this code file matches the
>   'inherits' attribute, and that it
>   extends the correct base class (e.g.
>   Page or UserControl).

Looks like it indicates a bigger problem.

**Fixed** Thanks for your help, the code contained a div with `runat="server"`. When I removed this it runs OK. This maybe because there is no form with `runat="server"` but I would expect a different error for that.

**As this question doesn't seem meaningful should I delete it?**

Comment: It is something else, at least with a quick test here, the above code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work actually. ASP.NET MVC will substitute all <%= ... %> or similar tags, it does not recognize whether it's a html definition or javascript. What is the output of your view? Is the "strange error" coming from Javascript or ASP.NET?

**EDIT**: regarding your update: make sure your Index.aspx has the "Codebehind" attribute (this is in Page-tag on the very first line) pointing to Index.aspx.cs and the attribute "Inherits" contains the class name of the Page/User-Control class in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://codeguru302.blogspot.com/2008/11/aspnet-make-sure-that-class-defined-in.html) for a possible solution to your error message.  Codebehind vs Codefile.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a HomeController with an Image method correct? Then it should be

```
<%= Url.Action("Image", "Home", new { id = image.Id })%>
```